# How do I set the default connection URL for mongo CLI?

Tags: mongodb

I cannot find anywhere to set the default connection URL for the mongo CLI. I want to be able to specify a particular username/password/hostname/database, which can all be specified as a URL. However, I want to just be able to type `mongo` instead of `mongo "mongodb://…"` in the shell.

I also don’t want the password to show up in `/proc/«PID»/cmdline`, but having it in a dotfile in my home directory is perfectly fine with me.

It doesn’t appear that `~/.mongorc.js` allows specifying the default connection string. But I would expect such an option to be available because the `mysql` CLI supports `~/.my.cnf` which allows you to specify username/password/hostname/database. So, where is this for `mongodb`?

EDIT: The solution has to work even if the `mongodb` at `localhost` is fully secured (no insecure local `test` database should be required—I thought this went without saying).

Answer (score 3):

You can run mongo shell commands in `~/.mongorc.js`. So you can just run the [connect](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/connect/) method in your `~/.mongorc.js`:

```
db = connect("mongodb://username:password@host:27017/myDatabase")
```

When you run `mongo` it will first connect to localhost, then connect to the database passed to the connect method.

A MongoDB server must be running on localhost, otherwise the mongo shell will error and exit before trying to connect to the other DB.

Run `mongo --nodb` to get around needing to connect on localhost before connecting to whatever is defined in `~/.mongorc.js`.

Comment: I’m sorry if this wasn’t clear, but I cannot use a solution which requires an insecure database at `localhost`. This solution cannot generalize because it prevents you from using it on the machine where `mongob` is configured to require authentication for the sole purpose of preventing random users from using a `test` database.

Comment: Additionally, did you even test this? The docs for [`connect()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/connect/) state that `mongodb://` URIs are not accepted and I remember getting an error when trying that during my own exploration of the issue last weekend.

Comment: I don't know where you got that from the documentation. It clearly says the url argument can be a connection string. You can use a username and password in the connection string too. Yes I tested it, yes it works.

Comment: Anyway, looks like you found out a good way of getting around having to connect to the database on localhost using --nodb. I'll add that to my answer so it's more complete.

Comment: I get https://gist.github.com/binki/b8e1fa4c18ce2b9aa031297fcbafca9f. In [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/connect/) I see “Specifies the connection string. You can specify either: * `<hostname>:<port>/<database>` * `<hostname>/<database>` * `<database>`”. When I use one of those forms, it works.

Comment: I will try updating to a 3.4 version of MongoDB, they probably added support for connection strings but didn’t update the docs or something. I’ll also complain to them about the docs being outdated if that’s the case. I’ll go ahead and accept my answer, I guess. Thanks for spending the time writing your answer—it does get partway there.

Comment: Huh weird. Might be a difference between shell versions? I tested it on 3.4 and it works. Maybe the later versions are less strict about what you put in for the connection string.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed a few places in the docs will say just "hostname:port/database" but you can use a full connection string. Anyway, glad you got to a solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

To directly launch `mongo` against a particular hostname/database/username/password without prompting for a password, without passing the password on the CLI, and without requiring an insecure database at `mongodb://localhost/test`, you can use this technique. Write [a script file which does the connection for you](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#mongo-shell-new-connections) and then [launch `mongo` with the appropriate arguments](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-nodb). For example:

`~/.mongo-do-auth.js`

```
// https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-nodb
// https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#mongo-shell-new-connections
//
// Run this with:
//
//     mongo --nodb --shell ~/.mongo-do-auth.js
db = connect('localhost/admin', 'root', 'asdf123');
```

And then, simply launch it from the CLI to get an interactive session:

```
sam ~ # mongo --nodb --shell ~/.mongo-do-auth.js
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12
type "help" for help
connecting to: localhost/admin
> quit()
```

Or, to run a script noninteractively, simply remove `--shell` and append your script. Consider a script:

`s2.js`:

```
print('connected to database ' + db);
```

To run:

```
sam ~ # mongo --nodb ~/.mongo-do-auth.js ~/s2.js
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12
loading file: /root/.mongo-do-auth.js
connecting to: localhost/admin
loading file: /root/s2.js
connected to database admin
```

However, this requires a lot of work and invoking `mongo` with arguments. It appears that this is a limitation of `mongo` because no one has suggested any alternative which works as smoothly as the `mysql` CLI client’s `~/.my.cnf`. This means that all shell scripts which directly invoke `mongo` will need to allow the the user to pass through `--nodb` and a path to a connection script instead of being able to rely on implicit per-user configuration.